# Dimensions validation rule cannot find validateDimensions()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I'm trying to use the image [dimensions validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-dimensions) for uploaded images inside a controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\ClassCategory;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Validator;

class ClassCategoryController extends Controller {
  public function store(Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
      'image' => 'dimensions:min_width=300,min_height=300'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) { // This is where the expection is thrown.
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

But it throws the following exception:

```
BadMethodCallException in Validator.php line 3181:
Method [validateDimensions] does not exist.

in Validator.php line 3181
at Validator->__call('validateDimensions', array('image', 'ballet.jpg', array('min_width=100', 'min_height=200'), object(Validator))) in Validator.php line 484
at Validator->validate('image', 'Dimensions') in Validator.php line 424
at Validator->passes() in Validator.php line 449
at Validator->fails() in ClassCategoryController.php line 42
at ClassCategoryController->store(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ClassCategoryController), 'store'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 80
at Controller->callAction('store', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(ClassCategoryController), object(Route), 'store') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
...
```

The class `Controller` uses `Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests`. What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

For future reference, I was getting [another exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37323495/dimensions-validation-rule-cannot-find-validatedimensions#comment62175538_37324147) because I didn't include the [`enctype` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp) in my form. This is needed if you're uploading files:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"></form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely to happen if you are using a different version of Laravel. Have you checked that you are using Laravel 5.2 and not a older version (like Laravel 5.1, where `dimensions` wasn't available).

You can check your version by running the following `artisan` command:

```
php artisan --version
```

You should then see something like:

```
Laravel Framework version 5.2.29
```

---

**UPDATE**

Run `composer update` to download `Laravel v5.2.32`.

You can verify that the method exists by running the command `grep -ri 'validateDimensions' vendor/*` and you should see:

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php:    protected function validateDimensions($attribute, $value, $parameters)
```

This function was only added to [Laravel recently](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/d56205159a4ec0581fcbe798a1a23c95c3f78459#diff-38fd116b7c7b8ac1bdd8362250d04d57), and was released in Laravel v5.2.32 on 17th May 2016.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Laravel 5.2: `Laravel Framework version 5.2.31`.

Comment: Did you happen to upgrade from an earlier version of Laravel to 5.2?

Comment: Nope, I started a new project using version 5.2 from scratch. Does it work for you?

Comment: Run `composer update` to get the latest version. The method is in `v5.2.32`.

Comment: Thanks, updating did the trick. Now I'm getting another exception, but I don't think it's associated.

Comment: Glad you got it working. If you need help with the new issue, post another question :)

Comment: Thanks, I will if I can't figure it out by myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `use` key word is used by PHP **per file** to import the used part.
so you have to declare the

`use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;` statement in your  **ClassCategoryController** page.

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

and then add the `use` statement to the class as follows:

```
class ClassCategoryController extends Controller {
    use ValidatesRequests;
    public function store(Request $request) {.....
```

Comment: I had tried this as well, but it makes no difference: it throws the same exception.

Comment: add this use statement  `use ValidatesRequests;` inside the class.